# AMPL Variables in subscripts are not yet allowed

Tags: ampl

I really hope someone can help with this...
This is what i have in the .mod file

```
set I := 1..10;
set J := 1..10;
set K := 1..2;
set W := 1..20;

param v{K, W};
param d{I, J};

var x1, integer;
var y1, integer;
var x2, integer;
var y2, integer;
var assist{W}, binary;
```

and this is the code generating error:

```
minimize nome: sum{w in W} (if (assist[w] == 0) then 
                    (if (x1 >= v[1,w]) then 
                        (if (y1 >= v[2,w]) then 
                            (d[x1 - v[1,w],y1 - v[2,w]])....
```

where the error regards the last line and says:

```
Variables in subscripts are not yet allowed.
context:  (d[x1 - v[1,w],y1 -  >>> v[2,w]] <<< )
```

this is one of constraints (others are just the same):

```
subject to rangex1:
x1 > 0 && x1 <= 10;
```

Comment: What solver are you expecting to use?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, you can't use decision variables within a subscript in AMPL. In this case x1 and y1 are decision variables, so `d[x1 - v[1,w],y1 - v[2,w]]` is not allowed. You'll need to reformulate the problem in a way that avoids this issue.